# React hook form Joi validation. No action after send

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form, joi

hook-form with Joi validation. I've set up all schema and connected it with my form exactly the same like in the doc, but after click submit, there is no action except move to the top of the form, There is no errors in console include errors from schema.validation. Anyone had same problem ?? I'll be thankfully for any tips

**Schema Validator**

```
export const JoiSchema = Joi.object({
  login: Joi.string().required().external(validateLogin),
  password: joiPassword
    .string()
    .minOfNumeric(1)
    .minOfUppercase(1)
    .minOfLowercase(1)
    .min(8)
    .max(16)
    .noWhiteSpaces()
    .required(),
  passwordConfirmation: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref("password")),
  name: Joi.string()
    .regex(/^[A-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]+[a-ząćęłńóśźż][^\s,.\\/-_]{3,19}$/)
    .required(),
  lastName: Joi.string()
    .regex(/^[A-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]+[a-ząćęłńóśźż][^\s,.\\/_]{3,30}$/)
    .required(),
})
```

**connect to useForm**

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: joiResolver(JoiSchema),
  });
```

**Register input**

```
<input
   name="firstname"
   {...register("firstname")}
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
/>
```

Before join schemaValidation I've consoled.log all fields and I had them in console, well they are registered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure all names are proper in the joiSchema and in form
if any field is missing it will generate error in that field but will not be shown anywhere.
and try using Controller from react hook form

Example:

```
  <label
    htmlFor="name"
    className="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font- 
    bold mb-1 mt-2"
    >
    Name
   </label>
   <Controller
    name="name"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
    render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
      <>
        <input
          {...field}
          id="name"
          type="text"
          className={`appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray- 
           700 border ${
            error?.message ? "border-red-800" : "border-red-800"
          } rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg- 
           white`}
        />
        {error?.message && (
          <span className="text-red-500 text-xs italic">
            {error?.message}
           </span>
         )}
       </>
     )}
    />
```

FieldState will provide error for particular field and make this into a reusable component which will reduce code duplication a lot

classes are of "tailwind"